# compilation error for R package ‘ape’ in macOS Monterey

Tags: c++, r, clang

I am trying to install "ape" library but I'm getting the following error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ape.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ape’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/ape’
```

I'm using macOS Monterey.

can anyone help, please?
thanks much

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the command uses to install and *all* lines in between? Often there are clues earlier in the output.

Comment: thanks much, I did add the lines where the warning message started. I'm installing with: `install.packages("ape")`

Answer (score 0):

solved, I just installed a recent gfortran.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).